# KnockoutJS Calling ViewModel function from inside another function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc, knockout-3.0

I'm having the following ViewModel in which I have few functions. And I am trying to call another function located in the same ViewModel.

*This is my ViewModel:*

```
var UploadFileListVewModel = function() {
var self = this;
```

*Inside I have an init function:*

```
//initialize view model
this.init = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Files/LastUploadedFiles',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {},
    }).done(function (result) {

        //doing stuff 
    });
}
```

Sometime later on I perform an remove file operation and once it completed I want to run my init fuction again

```
self.removeFile = function(item)
{
    $('#fileModal').modal('hide'); //closing modal dialog       

    $.ajax({
        //url: '@Url.Action("RemoveFile", "Files")',
        url: '/Files/RemoveFile',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'file_id': self.fileToRemoveId() },
        cache: false
    }).done(function (result) {

    //doing stuff 
    this.init();

    });     
}
```

I'm getting an error `this.init() is not a function`.

I would really appreciate if somebody could point me into right direction on how to call this init() function or suggest any workaround.

Comment: @Buzinas, this did the trick!!! Thank you. I cannot believe I spent half day trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword inside the callback function is not your ViewModel. That's why you created the `self`, so you can use it inside events, arrays, callback functions etc.

So, you should change your code to `self.init()`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It all works great now.